# Is there a way to retrieve unsubscribed phone numbers from Twilio?

Tags: python, twilio-api, twilio-python

I'm using Twilio in my application and right now this requires filling a table with the unsubscribed phone numbers.

I was looking into the Twilio documentation but I didn't find a specific endpoint to retrieve the unsubscribed recipients.

Is there a way to do that?

PD: My service is written in Python

Comment: What do you mean by unsubscribed numbers here? Do you mean numbers that are available for you to buy? Or numbers that you used to have but released?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: No. I'm talking about a phone number that doesn't want to receive SMS.

Imagine you have a phone number list to send SMS, for both promotions and notifications. But someone who doesn't want to receive SMS anymore can reply STOP to avoid receiving more SMS.

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-

Well, I'm interested to retrieve users' phone numbers that reply STOP. But I didn't find an specific endpoint

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134027-Twilio-support-for-opt-out-keywords-SMS-STOP-filtering-